# Yii2 @web alias is empty

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I don't understand why `Yii::getAlias( '@web' )` in my view file returns an empty string. `@webroot` returns the proper string.

Is there some configuration I'm missing?

Comment: I have put `<?= Yii::getAlias( '@web' ) ?>` in my view(frontend/views/site/index.php) and it return: `/yii2-app/frontend/web`

Comment: Do you have **pretty url** enabled and **showscriptname** set to false?

Answer (score 0):

@resting: `Yii::getAlias( '@web' )` is Predefined Aliases in framework. No such kind of issue that will create. I thing issue is somewhere else.

[Go through this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html)

Comment: I even did a `var_dump` and `die()` in `yii\web\Application.php` where `@web` is defined and its an empty string too. Weird. I have **pretty url** enabled and **showscriptname** false if that matters.